# Dynamic checkbox onchange & javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This might be an easy one for you, but I'm stuck, so I hope you can help me.

I'm creating checkboxes through a loop and want to specify a text somewhere in the website if a checkbox is clicked.

I'v seen solutions where a make a script for each checkbox, but that could turn out to be alot sometimes (something like this: `chckbx.onchange = function(){}` )

I'd rather have one function that is called from different checkboxes, but my javascript skills is basicly non-existing :)

This is what i got so far (which ofcourse dosn't work)
http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3BK/130/

Comment: Please post the code in your question. An additional fiddle is nice, but your question should work without external ressources.

Comment: your jsfiddle works if function not wrapped inside loader function, behaviour on jsfiddle, see with no wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3BK/134/

Comment: @Bergi I will remember that for the next time (will probably need help again hehe)

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok, now I just feel stupid ;) Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @user2532985 this is common issue for someone who is not accustomed to using jsfiddle, no problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have jQuery tagged in your question, so I'm going to provide a jQuery answer:

You'd use [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the event to a non-dynamic ancestor of your checkbox:

```
$('elem').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    ...
});
```

Where `elem` is a non-dynamic ancestor of your checkbox.

In your JSFiddle your checkbox *isn't* dynamic, but assuming it was, the closest non-dynamic ancestor of it would be the document's `body`. Therefore, we can use:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    testing('hello', '1');
});
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Sz3BK/135/)**.

You may want to extend this by passing in "hello" and "1" as [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test" data-newvalue="hello" data-spanid="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" data-newvalue="second" data-spanid="2" />
```

Here I've created two checkboxes with our two `data-*` attributes. In our jQuery method we can pull these values and pass them into our `testing()` function using [jQuery's `data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    testing($(this).data('newvalue'), $(this).data('spanid'));
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Sz3BK/139/).

We can then modify our `testing()` function to also use jQuery:

```
function testing(newValue, spanID) {
    $('#'+spanID).text(newValue);
}
```

This pulls our spanID (e.g. "1") and places it within an ID selector `$('#1')`, then modifies the text using jQuery's `text()` method. If you wanted to modify the HTML instead, jQuery also has a `html()` method for this purpose.

[**Final JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Sz3BK/140/).

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Thank you so much for the help (and thanks to all the other contributers as well)!! You not only provided the answer but an explanation as to why and how it works. Just great!

Answer (score 2):

because you are adding che checkboxes dynamicly,
to enable the change event for those added later, use code below

```
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3BK/136/ like this...

```
Add <head></head> in HTML code at top..

and change on load to "No wrap - in head"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
$('input[name=test]').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert("chk");
        // Checkbox is checked.
    }
    else
    {
        alert("unchk");
        // Checkbox is not checked.
    }    

});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3BK/137/). Hope it helps.